# Is it possible to extend an existing ribbon command using a task pane add-in?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I have an existing Word task pane add-in created using the Word JavaScript API. I'd like to extend an existing ribbon command (Mail Recipient) within this add-in somehow. Is this possible with JS, VBA, or a combination of the two?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "extend"?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky I'd like to clear the form fields of Mail Recipient when a button is pressed within my add-in.

Comment: Got it.  And are you trying to override the behavior of an existing Add-in, or are you OK with having your own Ribbon button or taskpane-button?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky I want to update this existing add-in that I've created. The button already exists within the task pane, I just want to add this extra feature to its click handler.